# Get the text of selected cell which is a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am having a problem with my asp project C#

i have a GridView that is created dynamically and each cell contains a buttonfield with link button type

i just wanna return back the text of the buttonfield when i clicked it

The problem actually in indicating the selected cell that i clicked

i could get the value of selected row but not selected cell

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

protected void gridviewRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Click")
   {
        e.CommandArgument<-- bind the text you wanna get

}

}

=================
CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("buttonfield values") %>'

or u can find the row in the grid index and the use

btnfield = gridview.rows[rowIndex].findControl("buttonfieldName") as buttonfield

Comment: to get the row index click u need in grid--- CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing but the e.CommandArgument returns the index of the row 

what i need is the index of column or cell 

This is my code:

if (e.CommandName == "click")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow selectedRow = v.Rows[index];
            string lastname = ((LinkButton)selectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            Session["name"] = lastname;
            Server.Transfer("~/change_shifts.aspx"); 
        }

But the problem is i don't wanna the value of cell[0]. i want the value of the cell i clicked

Comment: find the control once u have the row...
so did this work?.
btnfield = gridview.rows[rowIndex].findControl("buttonfieldID") as buttonfield;

string lastname = btnfield .text,
If this doesnt work paste ur html code.